# jQuery form validation: Define container for errors

Tags: jquery, validation, error-handling, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin, to validate my form. It works (places the error messages, next to the invalid input, which screws up my design), but I'd like to specify the error-container for every input field. I found the errorLabelContainer, but this puts all errors in one container.

Let's say, I have 2 inputs, one with id `name` and one with `firstname`. And let's also assume  I have 2 error spans, with ids `errorName` and `errorFirstname`. How do I tell jQuery to write the validation error for `name` into the span with the id `errorName`.

This is my current jQuery:

```
$("#form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            firstname: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Enter name"
            },
            firstname: {
                required: "Enter firstname"
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the `errorPlacement` option suits your needs:

> Customize placement of created error labels. First argument: The created error label as a jQuery object. Second argument: The invalid element as a jQuery object.

You can determine the element you want to place the error in based on the invalid element:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        firstname: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Enter name"
        },
        firstname: {
            required: "Enter firstname"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
        var name = $element.attr("name");

        $("#error" + name).append($error);
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/R3aEQ/

Comment: can you do this so that it is different at different stages of a wizard? How would you dynamically change errorPlacement?

Comment: You could have `errorPlacement` call a function that belongs to a workflow step. It really depends on how your workflow is structured though